# Problems converting/rounding long generated by System.nanoTime()

Tags: java

I'm currently writing a function that measures the amount of time it takes for certain parts of my code to finish their work. To accomplish this, I'm using System.nanoTime() to measure time taken.

It's split up into 2 methods, StartMeasure and StopMeasure(). StartMeasure() simply sets the starting time, like this:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
```

Then, when StopMeasure() is called, the current System.nanoTime() is subtracted by the startTime, leaving us with the time it took for the code to execute, in nanoseconds. I then try to convert this to milliseconds, then round it up to two decimal points.

```
long measuredTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
double convertedTime = (double) measuredTime / 1000000.0;
String finalTime = new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(convertedTime);
```

However, the values I get back when doing this are as follows:

```
measuredTime = 106164487952530
convertedTime = 1.0616448795253E8
finalTime = 106164487.95
```

There's definitely something going wrong with the division here, but I can't seem to figure out what. I'd like the result of finalTime to be "10.61" here. It works perfectly fine when I set measuredTime to a regular number rather than invoking System.nanoTime. I've looked at similar questions and also tried alternative solutions (TimeUnit conversion, among other things), but nothing seems to solve my problem.

Would appreciate any help. :)

Comment: It sounds like you are shadowing startTime so it stays 0 in your other method. Next, nano time returns nano-seconds.

Comment: You might be interested in https://visualvm.github.io/. It's usually better than implementing your own profiling

Comment: @matt cheers, that was exactly the problem. I'm pretty new to programming. Thank you! :)